# Decimal point getting ignored in excel vba

Tags: vba, excel

I have a macro running on excel which copies a number from one sheet to the other

First I store all the relevant numbers in a string array `va()` and than assign the array values in the new sheet.

`ActiveCell.Offset(0, 5).Value = va(i, 5)`

when number is -0,522004, I get the correct result in the new sheet, however when the number is -1,175378 I get -1175378,0000 as output in the excel sheet.

Note that I am using "," as decimal separator and "." as thousand separator.

I also tried to put `msgbox va(i,5)` and it shows -1,175378 as output but when the code is complete I get decimal ignored values.

Comment: Any reason in particular you are using a string array to store numbers?  (Is it some sort of key, value pair?) and also have you checked the formatting of the target cell that you are putting the value into?  I did a quick test on my machine and didn't seem to have any issues.

Comment: The array also has some text fields along with numbers so that is why I was using a string array. The solution provided by Rory using explicit coercion solved my problem :) . Thanks for effort though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your regional settings match the string data (i.e. comma is decimal separator), you can perform an explicit coercion:

```
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 5).Value = CDbl(va(i, 5))
```

Comment: Thanks Rory! you saved me from a lot of frustration